# Why is "$_GET" for password bad?

Tags: php, html

Can someone please explain why using "$_GET" for the password is bad?

I've been searching for a few days now, and cannot find the answer. Thanks!

EDIT: I heard it can be hacked. . . How is this possible / how would one do this?

Comment: Because it will be stored in the browser's history

Comment: $_GET means it comes over in the url like `example.com?username=joe&password=password123`, where anyone could look at the url and see it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- It makes the password visible to looking-over-the-shoulder attacks.
- It makes it more likely to be stored in log files.
- It makes it more likely to be stored in a cache — either on or off the computer the user is using (which might be a public computer) — and the browser's history).

Comment: An anecdote for "stored in logfiles" might be nick.com's server-status page being left open see http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/11/misconfigured-apache-sites-expose-user-passwords-other-private-data/

Answer (score 2):

$_GET function presupposes that the information is being sent via the address bar. That means it can be easily bookmarked, and therefore give out information that was sent through it.

I recommend you use the $_POST function, and "include" the password-processing .php file in the document itself (in index.php, for example). It is invisible once included, but it does it's job.

Answer (score 0):

All the $_GET value is visible in url query string because it is sent by url.
Quentin cleared the other points.
So don't use it for password or sensitive data field.